# How to increase the size of navigation history in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: configuration, intellij-idea, navigation

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or menu Navigate/Back navigates back in IntelliJ Idea. Only a limited number of times this shortcut can be used. Is there a configuration that can be used to increase the number of navigation history?

Comment: I rely on this feature heavily.  Especially when debugging a deep stack, this limitation is very annoying!  It should be an option under Settings/Editor (in "Limits" section)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the latest IntelliJ, this is no longer hard-coded, and can be changed via the Registry.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> (Windows) to pull up the Registry, search for "editor.navigation.history.stack.size", and edit the value.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, as of IntelliJ IDEA 14, [the size is hard-coded](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/fileEditor/impl/IdeDocumentHistoryImpl.java#L50).